# Ruby: Use Nested Arrays to Compile Values with Similar First Item

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a Ruby nested array like this:

```
arr = [["Red", 2], ["Red", 1], ["Yellow", 0], ["Yellow", 2], ["Blue", 1]]
```

And I'm trying to find a method that adds up the number (which is the second item in each mini-array) for similar items, yielding a nested array like this:

```
[["Red", 3], ["Yellow", 2], ["Blue", 1]]
```

I've tried for loops, and if statements, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it.

With a non-nested array you could just use `if` and `.includes?`, but I'm not sure how to work that with a nested array.

Any Ruby wizards able to steer me in the right direction here?

Comment: I edited to make your arrays to make them valid Ruby objects, and also assigned a variable to the input array. The latter allows readers to refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it. Also, these changes facilitate cutting-and-pasting to test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is not an array nor valid ruby

```
["Red", 3], ["Yellow", 2], ["Blue", 1]
```

anyway try this

```
arr.group_by { |color, amount| color }
   .map { |k, color_arr| [k, color_arr.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
 => [["Red", 3], ["Yellow", 2], ["Blue", 1]]
```

or from ruby 2.4.0 and upwards

```
arr.group_by { |color, amount| color }
   .map { |k, color_arr| [k, color_arr.map(&:last).sum] }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am very new at this and was actually able to piece it together!  Great explanation.

Comment: If desired, `arr.group_by(&:first)` and `color_arr.sum(&:last)`...

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(col,nbr),h| h[col] += nbr}.to_a
  #=> [["Red", 3], ["Yellow", 2], ["Blue", 1]]
```

Note the intermediate calculation:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(col,nbr),h| h[col] += nbr}
  #=> {"Red"=>3, "Yellow"=>2, "Blue"=>1}
```

See [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).